# SQL Count most used value in one column where other column equals something.

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a bit of a weird one I didn't know how to word the title please bear with me.

So I have a table like this which stores data on different jobs:

```
id | company | contact
----------------------
0  |  name1  |  Bob
1  |  name1  |  Mark
2  |  name3  |  Sam
3  |  name1  |  Bob
4  |  name2  |  Nigel
5  |  name1  |  Bob
6  |  name3  |  Donald
7  |  name1  |  Sandy
8  |  name3  |  Nigel
```

Is there a query with SQL I can use to query the table to find out the most commonly used contact for a particular company.

So the theoretical code I would be looking for would be something like:

```
SELECT "Most Commonly used Contact" FROM table WHERE company = "$company";
```

Is it possible in a single query or is this a multi query job?

Comment: Useful website for displaying questions like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1dbee/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you want to find the number of contacts grouped by each company, and then grouped by the actual contact. So in other words:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as num_contacts, `contact`, `company` FROM `jobtable` GROUP BY `company`, `contact` ORDER BY `company`, num_contacts DESC
```

Or for a single company:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as num_contacts, `contact` FROM `jobtable` WHERE `company`='$company' GROUP BY `contact` ORDER BY num_contacts DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

try this sql query...

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM table 
WHERE company = '$company'
GROUP BY contact 
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This query contains a syntax error. You can't add a `WHERE clause` *after* an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Tularis ohhh I am realy sorry.. Please check the edit.. **in hurry** I put `order by before where`...

Comment: Both work, but in this example it selects a lot of data I don't need because my table is much bigger than the one I gave in the example changing the first select fixes that. both are good answers thanks guys.

Comment: Sorry Nishant I took Tularis's answer over yours just because he was first but your answer is perfectly valid and thanks.

Comment: @Sam no worries dude.. welcome.. and I was the first one to answer your question.. hehe ;)

Comment: @NishantSolanki no worries, it happens. Removed the downvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Gives you the single most used contact for $company, if you can't use LIMIT (e.g. if you are utilizing an Oracle Database):

```
SELECT contact, used_by
FROM (
  SELECT contact, COUNT(*) AS used_by
  FROM table
  WHERE company = $company
  GROUP BY contact
) t
HAVING used_by = MAX(used_by)
```